# Want hp to inherit Stat and have current and max instead of manually making currenthp and maxhp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BaseStats : MonoBehaviour {
[System.Serializable]
public class baseStats {
    public string name;
    public int currentLevel;
    public int targetLevel;
    Stat currentHp = new Stat();
    public int maxHp;
    public int currentAp;
    public int maxAp;

    public int strength;
    public int toughness;
    public int agility;
    public int intelligence;
    public int willPower;
    public int luck;

    public int attack;
    public int hitPercentage;
    public int defence;
    public int evasionPercentage;
    public int abilityAttack;
    public int abilityDefence;
    public int abilityDefencePercentage;

    public int currentExp;
    public int targetExp;

        public baseStats(string Name, int CurrentLevel, int TargetLevel, Stat    CurrentHp,    int MaxHp, int CurrentAp, int MaxAp, int Strength, int Toughness, int Agility, int Intelligence, int WillPower, int Luck, int Attack, int HitPercentage, int Defence, int     EvasionPercentage, int AbilityAttack, int AbilityDefence, int        AbilityDefencePercentage, int        CurrentExp, int TargetExp) {    

        name = Name;
        currentLevel = CurrentLevel;
        targetLevel = TargetLevel;
        currentHp = CurrentHp;
        maxHp = MaxHp;
        currentAp = CurrentAp;
        maxAp = MaxAp;

        strength = Strength;
        toughness = Toughness;
        agility = Agility;
        intelligence = Intelligence;
        willPower = WillPower;
        luck = Luck;

        attack = Attack;
        hitPercentage = HitPercentage;
        defence = Defence;
        evasionPercentage = EvasionPercentage;
        abilityAttack = AbilityAttack;
        abilityDefence = AbilityDefence;
        abilityDefencePercentage = AbilityDefencePercentage;

        currentExp = CurrentExp;
        targetExp = TargetExp;

    }   
public class Stat{
    public int current;
    public int max;}
}

public baseStats mainChar;
void Start() {

    mainChar = new baseStats(
        "Truth",
        98,
        99,
        ,
        9999,
        754,
        999,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        255,
        100,
        255,
        255, 
        100,
        7773473,
        7777777);

    print(mainChar.currentHp);

}

  }
```

This is my code, ive been trying to get it where hp has a drop down in the inspector of current and max. I'm following the rpg tut from insurgent if you know of it, problem is hes doing it in unityscript and I need mine in c#. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: what are you suppose to do with Stat class? it seems useless anyway, you can put max and current in basestat

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

`Stat hp = new Stat() { current = currentHP, max = maxHP };`

Your question is very confusing. You want to *inherit* Stat, but you don't have a HP class that can inherit anything. It's hard to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make it where instead of making a currentHp and maxHp that I could just make hp and it get max and current from Stat. I seen a guy in a tut do it with unityscript and was trying to do it in c#. Thanks for answering :D